# scipy.misc.imresize deprecated but skimage.transform.resize gives different results

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-image

The [document](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html) of `scipy.misc.imresize` says that `imresize` is deprecated! Use `skimage.transform.resize` instead. But it seems `skimage.transform.resize` gives different results from `scipy.misc.imresize`.

For example, for [1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUiAH.jpg):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import resize
from scipy.misc import imresize
from imageio import imread

img = imread('1.jpg')
res = (1280, 1280)
img1 = resize(img, res) # np.float64, skimage
img2 = imresize(img, res) # np.uint8, scipy.misc
img3 = (img1 * 255).astype(np.uint8)
# from skimage import img_as_ubyte
# img3 = img_as_ubyte(img1)

np.count_nonzero(img3 - img2)
1748642
```

It is easy to find that `img2` and `img3` are obviously different, but when use `imageio.save` them, they look the same.

Comment: There are various differences under the hood: interpolation method, anti-aliasing, data type rounding, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try using scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom()